# Analyze the continuity of the following function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Here in my book I have such an exercise with the explanation given below, but still there is something the authors didn't add, but simply put "...after some operations...". Here is such an exercise:

```
Analyze the continuity of the following function:
```

$$f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R $$    $$ f(x,y)= \begin{cases}
\frac{3x^2y}{\sqrt{x^4+y^2}}& \text{if } (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\[2ex]
0& \text{if }   (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$$

In my book is writen, after some operations, we find that  $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^2 \setminus\{(0,0)\}$. What are these operation ? Thanks.

Comment: [tag:functional-analysis] (_the study of infinite-dimensional vector spaces, (...)_) is completely unrelated. Please read the tag excerpt before applying a tag.

Comment: What is the definition of a continuous function?

Comment: @AlexR Can you list these lemmas?

Comment: Yes, I will write them

Comment: @user46944 $\sqrt\cdot$ and all polynomials are $C^\infty$. The quotient of two continuous functions is continuous wherever the denominator is nonzero.

Comment: @Alex: $\lim_{t\to 0}f(t,t^2)=0$.

Comment: @AlexR 1) $f(x_0,y_0)$ is defined; 2) $\lim_{{(x,y)}\to{x_0,y_0}}=f(x_0,y_o)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $|y|\leq 1$, $$\sqrt{x^4+y^2}\geq \sqrt{x^4+y^4}$$
and thus

$$|f(x,y)|=\left|\frac{3x^2y}{\sqrt{x^4+y^2}}\right|\leq\underbrace{\left|\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+y^4}}\right|}_{\leq 1}|3y|\leq |3y|\underset{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{\longrightarrow 0}$$

therefore $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^2$.

Justification for $\left|\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+y^4}}\right|\leq 1$:

$$x^4\leq x^4+y^4\implies x^2\leq\sqrt{x^4+y^4}\implies \underbrace{\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+y^4}}}_{=\left|\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+y^4}}\right|}\leq 1.$$

Comment: To prove that the  function is continuous , do we have to show that its limit as it goes to zero, is zero ?

Comment: Yes, of course !

Comment: But my question was, how to show that the function is continuous on $R^2\{0,0}$

Comment: @JohnG. For that, just apply the lemmas I gave in a comment. Most work needs to be done for continuity at $(0,0)^T$, as idm showed you.

Comment: your function is clearly continuous on $\mathbb R\backslash \{(0,0)\}$. Moreover, I shown that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=0=f(0,0)$, therefore, $f$ is continuous on all $\mathbb R$ (because continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ too.

Comment: To prove the continuity on $(x_0,y_0)\neq (0,0)$ AlexR gave you the solution, $\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}f(x,y)=\frac{3x_0^2y_0}{\sqrt{x_0^4+y_0^2}}=f(x_0,y_0)$